# Error on Angular filter to edit a long json string to be on new lines in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I am new to coding and in my html (using Angular) I have the following call for json data from a database (Firebase):

```
<p>{{workout[0].box.info.training.strength.exercise[1].movement.freetext }}</p>
```

The following string is returned in HTML in one long line:

```
YGIG. Part A. 4 rounds of:. 3 min AMRAP. 400m run. Max RKBS in remaining time.  3 min rest between rounds. Part B. 4 rounds of: 3 min AMRAP. 400m row. Max Wall Balls in remaining time. 3 min rest between rounds
```

I would like the text to start on a new line every time there is a '.' and have created a filter, which generates an error message.

The HTML is:

```
<p class="specificmovt">{{workout[0].cfhackney.week417.metcon.freetext|myFilter}}</p>
```

The filter function is:

```
var app = angular.module('starter.filters',[]);

app.filter('myFilter',function(){
   return function(input){
   return input.replace(/\./g, '\n');
   };
});
```

The error message is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at http://localhost:8100/js/filters.js:5:17
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:21972:15), <anonymous>:4:500)
    at regularInterceptedExpression (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23054:21)
    at Object.expressionInputWatch [as get] (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:22956:26)
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24502:40)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:24778:24)
    at done (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19191:47)
    at completeRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19363:7)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19304:9)
```

As suggested by other StackOverflow posts, I've tried adding \n and the 'br' tag in place of the '.' into the JSON file to create a new line - but this does not work.

Would appreciate your help on finding out the most efficient way of getting my long JSON string onto new lines or fixing the filter function.

Thank you.

Comment: can you please console.log(input); inside the function you are returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your filter you should check if `input` is undefined at the beginning of your filter function and return if it is (since `undefined` has no replace function).

It gets called with undefined because Angulars first `$digest` cycle runs before your data is available.

This should work:

```
app.filter('myFilter',function(){
   return function(input){
       if(input == undefined){
           return;
       }
       return input.replace(/\./g, '\n');
   };
});
```

If you want to use '\n' for newlines you need to make sure that `white-space: pre` is set on the surrounding element. This will make your browser render the newlines.

I hope I could help :)

Comment: Thanks v much @vkluge for your help on this, which provided the result I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Your error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
```

is telling you that you are calling the replace method on something that doesn't exist, or more correctly, is undefined.

```
1. app.filter('myFilter', //this is a function which takes two arguments, a text string and then a function expression
    2. function(){ //this is another function which you are passing in as the second argument and is another scope
        3. return function(input){ //this is another function inside the previous function which you are passing an argument into as a variable(input).
            4. return input.replace(/\./g, '\n'); //you are performing actions on the argument you pass into the previous function. you have NAMED that argument input. However, you did not pass an actual argument to this function's scope. Therefore you are trying to .replace on something that is undefined.
         };
    });
```

We need to see what the value of input is. Then fix it. :-D

A fiddle that reproduces your error and subsequently fixes it:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrislewispac/pv8gebt1/

Comment: Thanks Chris for breaking down the problem - appreciate it.

Comment: I don't understand why you are having to use a regex though? Firebase is NoSQL and should return json to you?

Comment: Hi Chris.  The full json value was being returned - but I was hoping to format it and saw that other SO posts had used regex.  Still learning about Angular / NoSQL DBs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing how the data is returned. There has to be a better way to do this